# The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler

Tags: hlsl

I have an HLSL pixel shader:

```
struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;   
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

Texture2D s_texture : register(t0);

cbuffer ColorConstantBuffer : register(b1)
{
    float4 m_color;
};

SamplerState s_sampleParams
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = CLAMP;
    AddressV = CLAMP;
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float4 t = s_texture.Sample(s_sampleParams, input.texCoord);
    return t * m_color;
}
```

It works fine visually, but spams output with warnings:

D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: The Pixel Shader unit expects a Sampler to be set at Slot 0, but none is bound. This is perfectly valid, as a NULL Sampler maps to default Sampler state. However, the developer may not want to rely on the defaults.  [ EXECUTION WARNING #352: DEVICE_DRAW_SAMPLER_NOT_SET]

As you can see, I have set `s_sampleParams` so can anybody explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you use the effects framework, which will create a sampler for you (and bind it when you call Apply on EffectPass), using plain hlsl will not create sampler state by default, so you need to create one (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) )

Here is a verbose version here that matches the sampler you need;

```
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
samplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc= D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
samplerDesc.MinLOD = -FLT_MAX;
samplerDesc.MaxLOD = FLT_MAX;
```

Please note I left Border color as anything, since you want wrap it will nerver be used.

To create your sampler :

```
ID3D11SamplerState* myLinearWrapSampler;
HRESULT hr = d3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &myLinearWrapSampler);
```

Then call:

```
deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0,1, myLinearWrapSampler);
```

In order to attach the sampler to your pixel shader.

Since in your case your sampler settings matches the default one, setting sampler state to null is also valid (but I would still recommend to create one to clarify the intent, and avoid the runtime warning)

Comment: So, to be explicit, the code in brackets `{}` after `s_sampleParams` setting sampler properties is ignored, has no effect?

Comment: If you do not use effects framework, it is ignored indeed